# Gunicorn + Flask CRITICAL WORKER TIMEOUT when streaming video

Tags: python, flask, video-streaming, gunicorn

I have a setup to stream video from a webcam to a web interface using Flask running under Gunicorn. It works great for 30 seconds and then Gunicorn throws a worker timeout error. Gunicorn is started with the following command.

```
gunicorn3 --bind 0.0.0.0:5001 wsgi_cameras:app
```

To confirm that it is Gunicorn timing out the worker and killing it, we started it with this command:

```
gunicorn3 --bind 0.0.0.0:5001 --timeout 42 wsgi_cameras:app
```

When running with this command, it times out the worker at exactly 42 seconds.

```
def rear_frames():
    while True:
        success, frame = rear.read()
        if not success:
            error_msg = cv2.imread(CAMERA_FAILED_IMG, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
            ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', error_msg)
            data = buffer.tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n' b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + data + b'\r\n')
            break
        else:
            # Resize to standard width and height.
            frame = cv2.resize(frame, (FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT))
            # Convert data to bytes and yield result.
            ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            data = buffer.tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n' b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + data + b'\r\n')

@app.route('/rear_feed')
def rear_feed():
    return Response(rear_frames(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

`rear_frames()` is defined as a generator sending the multipart image to stream the video which shouldn't block the worker from sending its heartbeat. The worker stays alive the whole time as evidenced by the successful video stream.

Why does this setup cause the worker to not send the heartbeat which ends up getting it killed by the master?

Is there an alternative where I can send the heartbeat on behalf of the worker inside of the Flask app?

Comment: I'm having a very similar problem with a Docker/Gunicorn/FastAPI setup. The AI model in the back end eats up all CPU cycles to handle a request, and with too many requests at once, it seems the workers don't get time to trigger their heartbeat anymore. Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @downwash I did not find a solution.